# Blueprsim is not detecting any thing on page when object is ran from Process studio

Tags: blueprism

I'm facing an annoying issue in Blueprism a little help will be appreciated.
The error is when I run the task I have created in object studio directly in object studio it runs successfully but when I try to run the same task from process studio using action It throws an error. The application is launched but get this error. **(Application is  web-based.)**

```
Internal: Failed to perform step 1 in Read Stage 'Reader1' on page 'Main' - No elements match the supplied query terms
```

this is Application Modeller Settings
**Application Modeller**

[image]
[image]

And this is how I call it in Process

**Object Called in process**

[image]

**Action Properties**

[image]

Wait Settings are following

[image]

[image]

When I try to highlight the link it does highlight it.

Comment: Can you show printscreens from the object? Are you using wait stages before "Reader1" stage?

Comment: Yeah I'm using wait stage with 30 seconds. Ok Let me add those also.

Comment: @AndrzejKaczor I have updated the question please check. The only annoying part is when I run the same task from object studio it runs without error but when running it from the process it starts throwing this error.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your Read stage's configuration? You mentioned that the error is `Failed to perform step 1 in Read Stage 'Reader1' on page 'Main'` but you haven't shown us the way that stage is configured.

Answer (score 0):

I think that after your Reader1 should be a decision if element was found or not and then you can proceed with log-in. But I'd check if the element you're spying is working correctly. Maybe try passing value of reader from object to process.

Answer (score 0):

A process in BluePrism can have different speed of execution depending on the way you're running it.

If you're running application using "Step" function (hotkey F5), then BluePrism waits a long time between executing actions. A "Step above" (hotkey F10) is much faster, but the fastest possible speed of execution is from control room.

The delay from "Step", or "Step above" can be enough to make process work during the development. Once the process is moved to control room, then the delay is gone and sometimes the process might be running too fast. It can happen, that the BluePrism is trying to interact with the element that does not yet exist.

To make process work in control room, you need to have additional wait stages that will ensure that the process is not running ahead of the applications that are being automated. Whenever you're interacting with any element then you need to be sure that it exists.

i suspect that you're waiting for an element, but then you're trying to read a different one. It's important to wait for the exact element that you want to interact with, as elements can appear in an order, that can make your process crash.